# LM324N transimpedance amp for photodiode: Too low output, smaller feedback resistor gives greater output, not lower

Tags: amplifier, photodiode, transimpedance

I'm trying to build an optical power meter using a photodiode in photoconductive mode and a LM324N OpAmp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqK8s9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, the output voltage signal is very low. Exchanging R_f for a smaller resistor or even shorting it gives a higher output. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier, V_out / I_in = -R_f, so I would expect a smaller R_f to decrease the gain, not increase it.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: What sign is Vout? How far negative can Vout swing with 0V as the opamp's -ve supply rail?

Comment: Vout is positive and increasing with illumination, up to ~1 V when illuminated with a bright LED close to the photodiode. 
I don't think the output could swing lower than 0V for this device and circuit.

Comment: I_in and Rf are both positive, so check your signs and try again.

Comment: Well, but my oscilloscope says V_out is positive...

Comment: Operating outside the linear range of an opamp's input, phase reversals can happen. https://www.eetimes.com/the-phase-reversal-story/#

Comment: So your oscilloscope is ... not quite wrong, but misleading. With a single supply, use 2 resistors to fake an "0V" at Vs/2, and use that. Or go PV as Andy suggests, losing a bit of sensitivity and a lot of speed (not that the LM324 does speed)

Comment: @BrianDrummond So this phase reversal can happen when the input common mode voltage exceeds the specified limits (0...7.5V in this case). But shouldn't the ICMV be close to 0 due to the noninverting input being at 0V? Or is the issue that the OA for lack of a negative rail can't drag the inverting input to 0V and thus the voltage goes over the maximum limit? But in that case, shouldn't the ICMV as the average between the voltages of both inputs still be at < 7.5V, as (0V+9V)/2 in the worst case would give 4.5V?

Comment: @BrianDrummond could you elaborate on how the oscilloscope is misleading?

Comment: For now, simply add a -9V supply and try teh existing schematic otherwise unchanged.

Comment: @BrianDrummond will do, but I would appreciate some more explanation, I already learned a lot in this post.

Answer (score 3):

For Vout to successfully drag \$V_{IN-}\$ to equal \$V_{IN+}\$ (at 0 volts) it has to sink current from the photodiode (via \$R_F\$) towards a negative voltage. That can't happen because the lowest negative rail on the LM324 is 0 volts hence the output cannot force the circuit into equilibrium.

[image]

The red box in the drawing show the problem - the LM324 needs to have a negative rail when the photodiode is connected as shown.

On the other hand, if you changed the pins on the photodiode, it should begin to work because then the op-amp has to source current into the photodiode via \$R_F\$ and all should be well. Now you will need the photodiode cathode connected to ground: -

[image]

Comment: This'll work, but the OP wants photoconductive mode, while this is photovoltaic.

Comment: Correct. I could add a second supply for a negative bias to the diode, but first I would like to know if it is feasible with a single side supply.

Comment: @BrianDrummond the OP is building an optical power meter so I'm assuming that having a reverse bias on the PD is irrelevant for speed. If speed was important, then an LM324 would be out of the question. Plus, dark current would be a lot greater (I believe) and this is counter to the requirements for optical power measurement.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm actually building this for speed, which is why I chose reverse bias. I already found out that the LM324 is not good for higher speeds, but I wanted to at least get the circuit working before looking for alternative amps. Dark current is not a problem, as I'm actually dealing with quite high intensities.

Comment: @LukasK. what PD are you using - please link to the data sheet. Also, what speed are you actually talking about here? How quickly do you need to compute the power or, over what time frame are you averaging the power for a single measurement?

Comment: @Andyaka the PD is an [Osram SFH 203](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/gl/000154002DS01/datenblatt-154002-osram-fotodiode-5-mm-1100-nm-20-sfh-203.pdf). We're recording with 12.5 MSa/s, so ideally that fast - I realize now that that's way to much to ask the LM324 for. Before this, I used a reverse-biased LED with a BJT (no PD in the house; worked fine), but I wanted to change to a more linear setup.

Comment: I don't think 12.5 MSps is massively fast despite the capacitance of 11 pF falling to about 3 pF with 9 volts reverse bias. It looks fast enough for 12.5 MSps without a reverse bias IMHO. Try it. You'll also need to choose the op-amp with care and have a smidge of feedback capacitance to reduce noise gain maybe.